# Best way to get out of a for plotting for loop in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, loops

I have the following code in Matlab:

```
a = linspace(0,1);
t = linspace(0,10);
x = cos(2*t);

for i = 1:10
    z = a(i) *x
    plot(z)
    pause(0.1)
end
```

This is just to see how varying the variable "a" will change the plot. This created an animated plot.  Question is: If I have a large data set and I have to plot more complicate things than what is above, what is the best way to end the loop? In other words, if I now close the plot figure, it would continue to run until i = 10.  Would a "break" statement work? Or do a keyboard input with "keyboard"?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could check for the existence of the figure handle on every loop. If the figure is closed (and thus the figure handle is deleted) then you automatically end the loop.

```
a = linspace(0,1);
t = linspace(0,10);
x = cos(2*t);

h.fig = figure;
for i = 1:100
    z = a(i) *x
    plot(z)
    pause(0.1)
    if ~isvalid(h.fig)
        break
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you want the users to be able to end the animation when they feel like? Or do you want to end the animation programmatically due to a condition that's verified in every iteration?

If you just want to end the loop from within the code (that is, the second option above), then yes, a `break` statement will suffice. (You could set a boolean flag just before the `break` and check for this flag after the loop ends so that you can `close` the plot if you want to.)

Now, if you want to give the user the ability to stop the animation by clicking a button or something, you could (1) just tell the user to hit Ctrl+C; or (2) find a more structured solution to making an animation in matlab (you might want to check [this](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/animate-graphics-object.html)).

Comment: CTRL+ is not such a good option. If the plotting loop is large (i.e. has a lot of functions) it is very likely it will either a) break some java-based function and continue looping b)create a java exception and crash the whole MATLAB. Sometimes it works, but sometimes it doesnt